# Assignment operator in Go language

Tags: syntax, go

Lately I was playing with google's new programming language [Go](http://golang.org/) and was wondering why the assignment operator `:=` has a *colon* in front of the equal sign `=`.

Is there a particular reason why the authors of the language wanted to use `name := "John"` instead of `name = "John"`?

Comment: Great question and the answer is that using = for assignment is a mistake.  You learned early on that x + 2 = 4 is an equation not an assignment.  However, since assignment is far more frequent than checks for equality, some dominant languages started out using "=" for assignment early on... and the convention stuck.

Comment: @RickO'Shea - but Go also uses = for assignment.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

The `:=` notation serves both as a declaration and as initialization.

```
foo := "bar"
```

is equivalent to

```
var foo = "bar"
```

Why not using only `foo = "bar"` like in any scripting language, you may ask ? Well, that's to avoid typos.

```
foo = "bar"
fooo = "baz" + foo + "baz"   // Oops, is fooo a new variable or did I mean 'foo' ?
```

Answer (score 51):

```
name := "John"
```

is just syntactic sugar for

```
var name string
name = "John"
```

Go is statically typed, so you have to declare variables.

Comment: `name := "John"` is shorthand for `var name = "John"`.

Comment: @peterSO but `var name = "John"` is short for `var name string = "John"` which is short for the two lines given.

Comment: @Dave C: [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations) is explicit: "A short variable declaration ... is a shorthand for a regular variable declaration with initializer expressions but no types: `"var" IdentifierList = ExpressionList .`".

Comment: @peterSO I know, I read that too. That doesn't change what I said. This answer is correct.

Comment: Is there a philosophy for why Go uses this syntactic sugar? I feel that it hinders the readability of the language.

Comment: @KennethWorden How does it hinder readability? It minimizes unnecessary information. Languages with complete type inference are a good example of why this is a good thing.

Comment: @Joonazan Like I said, this my opinion. I feel that you may not know what type of variable you're initializing to... If you use `:=` which doesn't initialize to a primitive, when reading over someone else's code you'll have to look up what type the variable is. If you explicitly specify the type, then others who read your code will know what type the variable is, and be able more easily maintain your code.

Comment: Just wanted to add to the information that there are so many places the shorthand declaration comes in handy. e.g. `if el, exists := m["foo"]; exists {`

Answer (score 24):

`:=` is not the assignment operator. It's a short variable declaration. `=` is the assignment operator.

> [Short variable declarations](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations)
>
> A short variable declaration uses the syntax:
>
> `ShortVarDecl = IdentifierList ":=" ExpressionList .`
>
> It is a shorthand for a regular variable declaration with initializer
>   expressions but no types:
>
> `"var" IdentifierList = ExpressionList .`
>
> [Assignments](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments)
>
> `Assignment = ExpressionList assign_op ExpressionList .`
>
> `assign_op = [ add_op | mul_op ] "=" .`

In Go, `name := "John"` is shorthand for `var name = "John"`.

Answer (score 18):

Rob Pike [explains](https://youtu.be/3DtUzH3zoFo?t=16m7s) why Go has `:=` during his talk "Origins of Go" (2010).

`:=` was a pseudo operator in another language codesigned by Pike called Newsquek (1989). 
Which had Pascal-ish notation and ability to infer type for declare and initialize idiom ([page 15](http://go-lang.cat-v.org/talks/slides/emerging-languages-camp-2010.pdf))

```
// variable: [type] = value
x: int = 1
x := 1
```

*Marginal note:* Robert Griesemer [brings up](https://youtu.be/p9VUCp98ay4?t=20m27s) `:=` operator answering the question "What would be one thing you take out from Go?" during QA session at Google I/O 2013. Referring to it as *convenient but problematic*.

Answer (score 10):

There is at least one subtle difference between

```
name := "John"
```

and

```
var name = "John"
```

The former is a non-declaration statement and not allowed outside of a function body, whereas the latter is a valid statement at the package level.

Answer (score 6):

**Important Context for the Answer:**

`:=` is a shorthand operator for initializing a variable. In **Go**, the following operations are equivalent:

```
var myNumb String = "one"
myNumb := "one"
```

**Answer:**

The implied question now is: "Why did go design the shorthand notation `:=` to have a `:` before the `=`?". The reason is to prevent prevalent typos. If the shorthand assignment operator was just `=`, then you could have the following situation:

```
var myNumb String = "one"
myNumb = "two"
```

Now did the user who created that code intend to reassign `two` to `myNumb`, or did he mistype `myNumb` instead of correctly typing `myNumbTwo`? By including the colon in `:=`, the programmer would have to commit two errors (forget the colon and forget the `var`) in order to have a bug, hence decreasing the probability of doing so **drastically**.

Answer (score 5):

Both are the different technique of variable declaration in Go language.

```
var name string = "John" // is a variable declaration
```

AND

```
name := "John"   // is a short variable declaration.
```

A short variable declaration is a shorthand for a regular variable declaration with initializer expressions but no types.

Read below for detail:

[Variable declarations](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Variable_declarations)

[Short variable declarations](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations)