# Understanding slice assignment in Go

Tags: go

In the below code snippet, what exactly is the line after the `if` block doing

`slice = slice[0:l+len(data)]`?

```
func Append(slice, data []byte) []byte {
    l := len(slice)
    if l + len(data) > cap(slice) {  // reallocate
        // Allocate double what's needed, for future growth.
        newSlice := make([]byte, (l+len(data))*2)
        // The copy function is predeclared and works for any slice type.
        copy(newSlice, slice)
        slice = newSlice
    }
    slice = slice[0:l+len(data)]  // <-- What is this doing ?
    for i, c := range data {
        slice[l+i] = c
    }
    return slice
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess

```
slice = slice[0:l+len(data)]
```

changes `slice` length, so you can add new elements.

> You can extend a slice's length by re-slicing it, provided it has sufficient capacity.

[reference](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/11)

Comment: No, the slice had its capacity extended by the 3 statements right above it. The only thing it did was reassigning the original values and "0" to the extra positions, but it was also a waste, as Go had already filled them.

It was also a second waste, as the loop right after it redefined all those values too.

So, the line has no use at all.

Comment: Please, take a look at my answer for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

just expand the len(slice) ,so can append data, remove this this statement,  slice out of index occurs...In addition，copy return the min len(src) and len(dst), so when execute `if l + len(data) > cap(slice)`,the len(slice) would be 0

Answer (score 0):

Just posting this answer for future reference.

That line has no use. The slice's capacity was extended by the statements right above it.

```
        // Allocate double what's needed, for future growth.
        newSlice := make([]byte, (l+len(data))*2)
        // The copy function is predeclared and works for any slice type.
        copy(newSlice, slice)
        slice = newSlice
```

The first line created a bigger slice called "newSlice".

In the second one "slice" had its content copied to "newSlice".

And then, "newSlice" was kind of cloned back to "slice".

Yeah, Go does feel strange about this thing, as not also the content is copied, but "slice" now has the same capacity as "newSlice". But it is not like a "pointer assignment" in C, as we still have two different slice instances and what happens to one doesn't affect the other. Please note the usage of the assignment operator "=" instead of the short variable declaration operator ":=", as noted in [this answer in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16521472/assignment-operator-in-go-language)

What was actually done was the assignment of the original "slice" values and "0" to the "newSlice" extra positions, but it was also a waste, as Go had already initialized them as "0" in the `make()` statement.

It was also a second waste, as the loop right after it redefined all those positions along with the rest of the content in "data". This [link](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/16) may help with the loop meaning.

So, the line has no use at all and you should remove it.