# Reading files in bytes

Tags: go

I'm trying the below code, to read 2 files, and remove somelines from top and from bottom, but looks I've issue in reading the file.
my code is:

```golang
//file: clean.go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func clean(files ...string) {
    for _, fn := range files {
        var f *os.File
        if f, err := os.OpenFile(fn, os.O_RDWR, 0); err != nil {
            log.Fatal("error", err)
        }
        defer func(f *os.File) {
            if err := f.Close(); err == nil {
                log.Fatal("error", err)
            }
        }(f)

        if fileBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(f); err != nil {
            log.Fatal("error", err)
        } else {
            lines := strings.Split(string(fileBytes), "\n")
            if fn == "currentInvenory.csv" {
                lines = lines[12 : len(lines)-5]
            } else {
                lines = lines[12 : len(lines)-6]
            }
            fmt.Println(fn, "has a total of", len(lines), "lines")
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    files := []string{"currentInvenory.csv", "currentTransactions.csv"}
    clean(files...)
}
```

But got this error:

```sh
.\clean.go:14:6: f declared but not used
```

Comment: There is a typo `f, err := ...` to `f, err = ...`

Comment: The [short variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations) in `if f, err := os.OpenFile( ...` defines a new variable `f`.  This new variable is not used.

Comment: remove the colon from `:=` in the condition and declare `err` just like it. You have two `f` variables in different scopes hence the error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assignment operator in Go language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16521472/assignment-operator-in-go-language)

Comment: @RisingSun then I get the `err` as `undeclared name: err`

Comment: @Зелёный  then I get the `err` as `undeclared name: err`

Comment: @MuffinTop  then I get the `err` as `undeclared name: err`

Comment: i meant to say you need to declare `err` just like `f`

Comment: @RisingSun So, what could be the `err` type, I ried `string` but it failed with `if err !=nil`

Comment: error in go has a special type `error`. BTW your defer fuction is useless since you have a loop, while defer fire only an fuction exit.

Comment: Use a [variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations) to declare the variable: `var err error`

Comment: @Зелёный so how can I ensure the files are closed properly?

Comment: close it at the end of the iteration.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thanks to the comments above, the problem is `if f, err := os.OpenFile( ...)` defines a new variable `f`, this new variable is not used. There are two potential solutions:

```golang
f, err := os.OpenFile(fn, os.O_RDWR, 0)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("error", err)
}
```

Or

```golang
var f *os.File
var err error
if f, err = os.OpenFile(fn, os.O_RDWR, 0); err != nil {
    log.Fatal("error", err)
}
```

So, my full working code now is:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "sync"
)

func clean(files ...string) {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for _, fn := range files {
        wg.Add(1) // Launch several goroutines and increment the WaitGroup counter for each.
        go worker(fn, &wg)
    }
    wg.Wait()
}

func main() {
    files := []string{"currentInvenory.csv", "currentTransactions.csv"}
    clean(files...)

}

func worker(fn string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()

    var f *os.File
    var err error
    if f, err = os.OpenFile(fn, os.O_RDWR, 0); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("error", err)
    }

    defer func() {
        if err := f.Close(); err != nil {
            log.Fatal("error", err)
        }
    }()

    if fileBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(f); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("error", err)
    } else {
        lines := strings.Split(string(fileBytes), "\n")
        if fn == "currentInvenory.csv" {
            lines = lines[11 : len(lines)-6]
        } else {
            lines = lines[11 : len(lines)-7]
        }
        fmt.Println(fn, "has a total of", len(lines), "lines")
        if len(lines) > 0 {
            var ctx = []byte{}
            for _, s := range lines {
                ctx = append(ctx, []byte(s)...)
            }
            ioutil.WriteFile(fn, ctx, 0644) // want (string, []byte, os.FileMode)
        }
    }

}
```